# It's a bird... it's a plane... it's... hero text?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are currently showing the following text on the main page, above the 'Top Questions' header:

```
docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);
```

Edit: Confirmed a few minutes later that this has propagated to the main site.

**Meta Screenshot:**

[image]

**Main Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: copy/paste fail when refactoring some view logic, and that only shows up some of the time :/ Pushing a fix in a moment.

Comment: Same here. This is also happening in other StackExchange sites too.

Comment: I'm seeing it on main now.

Comment: It's fixed for me.

Comment: @MichaelStum I take it you've noticed the "This is also happening in other StackExchange sites too" comment?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, thanks for mentioning it. Rolling back to the previous build, then double, triple and quadruple checking the view. Still looking at what happened, but basically, it's a banner that isn't always shown, so I didn't see it and it doesn't always show for everyone. Sorry about that!

Comment: Use React noob.

Comment: Properly fixed it and rolled out the latest build again. [Hero working as expected again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37Tl17aDZC4)